# Storing Languages (utf8_general_ci)

Tags: mysql, collation

I have to store a number of different languages in a MySQL Table.
eg: Japanese & Chinese in the native formats

Currently the table I'm using has the Collation set to: `latin1_swedish_ci`

I read somewhere on the Internet I should use the Collation: `utf8_general_ci`

Is this correct?
Is there a better option?
Any language limitations I should be aware of?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it's correct and because of it's a very easy solution I don't see the need for a "better option".

Answer (score 0):

utf8_general_ci is the standard  for multi-language support. I noticed when I started a data-based site recently that latin1_swedish_ci was the default collation type for my new tables (MySQL 5.0.45 / MySQL 5.0.67). I had to keep checking that this was corrected since the collation type for the database connection can differ from new tables, or even from one table to the next.

Also, check that your charset for the database and for the pages is UTF-8 Unicode (utf8). Somewhere in the html head should be a line similar to:

```
<html>
  <head>
    [...]
    <meta http-equiv = "content-type" content = "text/html; charset = UTF-8" />
    [...]
  </head>
  <body>
    [...]
  </body>
</html>
```

The you can use a simple switch in .php to include / require the correct language file (which might have local defs or read language defs from database, for example), such as:

```
switch ( $language )
{
  case 'en' : include $path . 'english.php'; break;
  case 'fr' : include $path . 'french.php';  break;
  [...]
}
```